# Most Keywords Possible In Declaration

Tags: c++, keyword

Purely out of curiosity I have been wondering how many keywords can fit in a declaration.
Assuming templates don't count(because infinity), the longest one I could come up with was:

```
extern const unsigned long int i;
```

I was trying to fit new in there too.

I looked this up a bunch, but didn't see anything about it. Just for fun!

**EDIT-**
Since this is too broad of a question, how about you can only fit in a keyword once for each different keyword. No exceptions. Of course long long is a perfectly legitimate type, I just want to know how many different ones can be used together. So given that, how many keywords can fit in one declaration. Could be a function, member function, or variable.

Comment: how do you meaningfully mix `extern` and `mutable`?

Comment: you can replace one of them with `volatile`.

Comment: also how do you mix `unsigned` and `double`?

Comment: replace `double` with `int`.

Comment: extern struct { int f1; ... int f1000000; } foo;

Comment: You can probably replace `extern` with `static inline` for a function

Comment: `comstexpr` somehow?  Also note that a function poimter can have keywords attached to arguments.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf yeah sorry, I was messing around with switching things and forgot to see if it compiled!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You said declaration. Here's a [function declaration](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8471b554bf4353c5) with ten total in a messed up order for kicks:

```
int inline long constexpr volatile static unsigned const long foo() noexcept;
```

You can do twelve with a [member function](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2382480273b61adb):

```
virtual int inline long constexpr volatile unsigned const long foo() const noexcept = delete;
```

I don't know how you'll take this, but I believe this to be a valid twenty on a [variable declaration](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72fe011eadd6f721), not including possibilities for initialization (though not including that, but including `decltype` is questionable):

```
alignas(sizeof(decltype(typeid(const volatile unsigned long long int)))) static thread_local decltype(typeid(const volatile unsigned long long int).name()) foo{};
```

It's kind of hard to know what to keep away from when there are so many possibilities for infinite repetition. For example, my variable declaration has no casts, and this is why I said allowing `decltype` is questionable:

```
int i;
decltype(const_cast<const int &>(const_cast<int &>(const_cast<const int &>(i)))) foo{i};
```

Comment: You can add `override` to the member too.

Comment: Oh and the `[[noreturn]]` attribute

Comment: What's a `volatile` `constexpr`?

Comment: @user657267, `override` is not a keyword, nor is the attribute.

Comment: @Adam, A `constexpr` function that returns a `volatile` blah, where blah is that long return type.

Comment: Awesome! These things are out of my area of understanding so I didn't know what to say other than as many keywords as possible. If it should be a competition, a keyword should only be able to be used 2, 3 or 4 times each, or maybe someone with more knowledge should figure out rules, but i'm pretty happy with these. Thanks for posting!

Comment: what about `resumable`? (from C++14) ;)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, Oh, did that get accepted?

Comment: @LeonFrickenschmidt, At first thought, I'd say only being able to use each keyword once per meaning. So one `long` would mean from `int` to `long int` and the other would mean from `long int` to `long long int`, while the ones inside a `decltype` would be the same, but separate due to the different context, yet I'm sure this folds on itself along the way.

Comment: @chris The original spirit of the question was "How many properties can I give something". So as long as it doesn't open the possibility of infinite repetition, I'm fine with that. But does it open that possibility?

Comment: @LeonFrickenschmidt, Well, think of it this way. `long long int` is perfectly valid to use. I would say a single `const_cast` would also be valid. You could have a `const_cast<long long int &>`, and have `long long int` used again. I'm not really saying I have a great grasp on what exactly the longest valid one *is*, though.

Comment: @chris I don't know (yet), but accepted or not, is a candidate to enlarge a function declaration, don't you think?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster, True.

Answer (score 12):

Here is one that is practically infinite:

```
thread_local constexpr static const unsigned long long*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const*
const* const* const* const* const* const* const* const* i{nullptr};
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0d1516da6b0a8a15)

Comment: This (I presume so anyway) made my computer halt for a few seconds for some strange reason. I count things that can be chained infinitely as cheating, though.

Comment: Rofl, yeah, that's funny, I was going to say things that go to infinity don't count, but I didn't even know of any, so thanks!